# http://sigmajs.org/ les mis tutorial - why are my canvases 0 height?

Tags: javascript, html, canvas, sigma.js

I'm working through the http://sigmajs.org/ les miserable tutorial. I'm curious, when I run a local server and view my [index.html](https://github.com/micahstubbs/les-mis-tut/blob/master/02/index.html) page, why are the canvases generated by sigmas.js 0 height?

[image: 0 height canvases in chrome]

https://github.com/micahstubbs/les-mis-tut/blob/master/02/index.html

Comment: Maybe so that they are present in the DOM? Sigma might need access to it later on.

Comment: makes sense. would expect something to render and be >0 height. I copied and pasted the example, but still no network is visible. hhhmmm

Comment: Sigma's [`sigma.renderers.canvas.js`](https://github.com/jacomyal/sigma.js/blob/master/src/renderers/sigma.renderers.canvas.js) class is responsible for initializing contexts i.e. `this.initDOM('canvas', 'scene');`. If you are not using it, then it will hide the canvas by setting its height to zero.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because your CSS code is false.
Replace it with this :

```
 #sigma-container {
  position :absolute;
  width :500px;
  height :500px;
  }
```

Comment: beautiful. with this change, the network renders.  many thanks!